# sails.io.js script called twice

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

i have an issue with my sails application.

All of my js script are called twice but my less file are correctly called only one time.

[image: In my IDE]

[image: In my firefox inspector]

This problem is present on chrome/edge/opera/firefox

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I remove the the script command and they are called only one time but it's not how it's supposed to work right ?

Comment: Is this a view, or an html file?

Comment: Hi, it's in a view

Comment: can you paste a snapshoot of the view and the layout? (source)

Comment: Sounds like a grunt problem. Have you modified any of your grunt processes? Do the extra copies show up only in the browser, or can you see them in the view file in your code editor after sails lift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a guess based on what you've shown us, but I wonder, do you have the open-and-close script tags: `<!--SCRIPTS-->` and `<!--SCRIPTS END-->` in both your view file, and in your layout file?

The default layout file is `views/layout.ejs`, and the default can be set/changed in `/config/views`. If you are using the layout and it is in your `views/` folder, then grunt is likely adding scripts to it as well as your specific view file. You should remove the script tags from either the layout or your specific view files, and (if this is the source of error) that will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Sails was actually calling my layout.ejs and there was open and close script tags. I simply remove layout.ejs from my /config/views.